# How to generate big number of SIP requests

Tags: performance, request, sip, sip-server

I need to test an application that processes SIP requests. For now, I want to test the performance of the application, so I need a way to generate a big number of SIP requests.
I know there are tools for this (like SipP), but I don't know what is the maximum number of requests that a single computer can really send in a particular time interval.
I never done this type of test, i need help.

Thanks

Comment: generally, when u talk of performance of telephony apps its the call establishment time rather than how much request could be sent which determines your perf....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well sipp can generate requests pretty quickly and if you're testing call set up and tear down, i.e. INVITE requests an d associated transaction processing, it's almost certainly the tool for the job.

If you're not concerned about SIP transaction processing and instead just want to bombard your server with SIP requests you could just whip up a console application with a UDP socket and send dummy requests by using a template request and modifying the following:

- The branchid parameter on the Via header,
- The tag parameter on the From header,
- The Call-ID header.

Since your app will only be doing a few string search and replaces and a UDP send it will be able to generate requests probably a 100 to 1000 times faster than a server on the same hardware, that needs to parse and understand the requests, will be able to process them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you know also if there is a similar tool but for ENUM requests? (I've seen a tool of Nominum called DNSperf but I don't know if it works with ENUM).

Comment: I don't know of a tool but since ENUM records are just DNS entries any DNS stress test tool would do. DNS queries are even simpler than SIP packets so you feasibly use the same approach outlined above with the UDP socket.

Comment: Do you know approximately the number of SIP requests that can be sent in one second (or another unit of time) using SIPp? If no, do you have a way to check this?