# ENUM requests simulator

Tags: dns, request, simulator

I'm searching a ENUM simulator that can send a big number of requests in a time interval (per second for example). I've seen there is a tool called DNSperf (of Nominum) but I don't know if it also works with ENUM.

Thanks

Comment: The question has been answered in another post. Because the ENUM requests are DNS entries, you can use a tool that generates DNS queries like DNSperf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use DNSPerf - ENUM queries are just standard queries for `NAPTR` resource records in a particular domain tree.

Comment: Do you know how to check the maximum number of DNS queries that DNSPerf can send per unit of time?

Comment: @MickaelMarrache  you want to limit it?  AFAIK dnsperf can't do that, although tcpreplay can.

Comment: No I want to measure the number of DNS requests that can be sent by DNSPerf per second for example. I'm doing benchmarks on a DNS server, and I want to be sure that X queries have been sent by my client in one second. I need to know how many queries the server can process at a time.

Comment: I thought about using Wireshark and counting the number of DNS queries sent per second using the Time column. But, I don't know if it's accurate.

Comment: @MickaelMarrache dnsperf will tell you how many it sent - you'll find that the server will be the bottleneck, not dnsperf.  I've seen dnsperf handle around 100,000 queries per second.

Comment: How can you be so sure that DNSperf can send around 100,000 queries per second? Did you test it? Also, do you have a methodology to measure the number of DNS queries that can be processed by the server each second?

Comment: @MickaelMarrache yes, I've tested it (extensively).  And for your latter point, that's _exactly what DNSperf is designed to do!_

Comment: Okay, but what about the network limitations? I guess I need to connect the client and server using high data rate connection?

Comment: @MickaelMarrache yes, I'd recommend GigE to ensure that the network itself doesn't constrain your benchmarks.

Comment: Last thing, I'm also looking for a tool for generating SIP calls to test a SIP server. I've heard about SIPp but I also have the same question, how many SIP requests can be sent per second? If you have informations on this subject, it would be nice if you can answer in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878304/how-to-generate-big-number-of-sip-requests). Thanks

Comment: @MickaelMarrache please ask a new question - probably on serverfault.com, as this is a system engineering question, not a programming one.